# Configuring database for integration tests in micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-client

I am trying to write an integration test in micronaut.

I have a controller class:

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @Inject
    private HelloRepository helloRepository;

    @Get("/")
    public HttpResponse get() {
        return HttpResponse.ok(helloRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

I am trying to write an integration test for it like:

```
@MicronautTest
public class HelloControllerSpec {

    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;

   @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception {
        try(RxHttpClient client = embeddedServer.getApplicationContext().createBean(RxHttpClient.class, embeddedServer.getURL())) {
           client.toBlocking().exchange("/hello").status();
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
 No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
```

My application.yml file that I put under "src/test/java/resources/" has the following datasource implementation:

```
datasources:
   default:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
      driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
      username: sa
      password: 'sa'
      schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
      dialect: H2
jpa:
   default:
      packages-to-scan:
         - 'com.myproject.project'
      properties:
         hibernate:
            hbm2ddl:
               auto: update
            show_sql: true
```

I have also included this in my build.gradle file

```
runtime 'com.h2database:h2'
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Edit: This is my repository class

```
@Repository
public interface HelloRepository extends CrudRepository<BufferConditionEntity, Long> {}
```

Comment: Can you show the source code for `HelloRepository`?

Comment: Okay. I've added it in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to solve this?

Yes.

The particulars of how to do that will depend on knowing more about your project. 
 You haven't shown enough information to know what is wrong so I pasted your code into a project which shows that the code in your question appears to work.  The only thing that isn't clear is what your `initMocks` method does.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajshreerairepository.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajshreerairepository/blob/4abe71d7a4ac9ae3cbcdb164f4d2c58249e29106/src/main/java/com/myproject/project/HelloController.java

```
package com.myproject.project;

import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @Inject
    private HelloRepository helloRepository;

    @Get("/")
    public HttpResponse get() {
        return HttpResponse.ok(helloRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajshreerairepository/blob/4abe71d7a4ac9ae3cbcdb164f4d2c58249e29106/src/test/java/com/myproject/project/HelloControllerTest.java

```
package com.myproject.project;

import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient;
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@MicronautTest
public class HelloControllerTest {
    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception {
        try (RxHttpClient client = embeddedServer.getApplicationContext().createBean(RxHttpClient.class, embeddedServer.getURL())) {
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, client.toBlocking().exchange("/hello").status());
        }
    }

    void initMocks(Object o) {
        // unclear if this method is relevant
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajshreerairepository/blob/87898caad4699436c60c84b85058d29885e7ec9f/src/main/java/com/myproject/project/HelloRepository.java

```
package com.myproject.project;

import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface HelloRepository extends CrudRepository<BufferConditionEntity, Long> {
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajshreerairepository/blob/87898caad4699436c60c84b85058d29885e7ec9f/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: rajshreerairepository
---
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: 'sa'
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: H2
jpa:
  default:
    packages-to-scan:
      - 'com.myproject.project'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        show_sql: true
```

That test passes.

Comment: is there a way to load the data in db? spring auto loads data with filename data.sql from classpath.  Does micronaut-data supports any similar feature?